# Connect to SQL Server with user credentials of another domain

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

How can I connect to a SQL Server database using user login/password that is in another domain?

If I use my account to connect to DB, it works fine:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server_name;DATABASE=testdb;UID=MY_Domain\\username;PWD=pass; Trusted connection=YES')
```

But I need to use another user's credentials like

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server_name;DATABASE=testdb;UID=Another_Domain\\username;PWD=pass; Trusted connection=YES')
```

When I try the latter I get an error of "failed login for MY_Domain\username" rather than
for the user "Another_Domain\username".

In both cases by running SQL Server Management Studio I can use Windows Authentication to connect to the db.

Comment: it's a good question. How can I check this? There is an interesting thing that I can connect to ms sql server if I run Managment Studio on behalf of that user rights

Comment: no, there wasn't. I think the trouble is that there's no trust permission between both domains

Comment: No, it's not. Please read answer below. If there was no trust then it would not work from SSMS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not pass a `UID` and `Password` and set `Trusted_connection=True` (your second connection string) to connect as a (impersonated) windows user. You can either connect as a SQL Server user (username and password) or as a windows authenticated user (trusted connection).

Your code should impersonate the windows user (as SSMS does) and then set `Trusted_connection=True` *only*.

This MSDN page [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an example.

Since this works from SSMS it suggests there is the necessary trust between the domains.

Comment: @S4nd33p Hey, i'm running into the same problem, can you tell me how you solved it ? Did you find a way using python ? Thank you for your time

Comment: yes, @Tbaki, I could connect through python. Actually, you either should let the program handle it automatically by not entering the trusted connection clause, or set Trusted_connection=False while passing valid UID/PWD. Example : cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+str(os.environ['DataSource'])+';DATABASE='+str(os.environ['Database'])+';UID='+str(os.environ['userID'])+';PWD='+str(os.environ['password']))

Comment: @S4nd33p Thanks, it helped me a lot !